# How do I format my section/subsection titles without changing the cross-referencing result

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I am using some code recommended by the editor of a journal.  However, the `\renewcommand` line for `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection` seems to be causing a problem with the cross-referencing function `\ref`.

When I reference a subsection (e.g., 'II.A') it only displays "A" or a subsubsection (e.g., 'II.A.1') I just get "1".

Is there a way to fix this code so that it properly references the subsections with the section number included.

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, reqno]{article}

%load packages
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} %overwrites 1.5" default margins   from    article class
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}% popular packages from the American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{bm}% Bold Math package
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color} %colored text
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort,compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{titlesec} %for formatting section titles
%\usepackage{appendix}


%% SECTION TITLE FORMATTING
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} %numbering
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont \bfseries \raggedright \uppercase}
  {\thesection.} %numbering
  {0.5em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} %numbering
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont \bfseries \raggedright}
  {\thesubsection.} %numbering
  {1em}{}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}} %numbering
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont \bfseries \itshape \raggedright}
  {\thesubsubsection.} %numbering
  {1em}{}
```

Comment: I don't see anything there that affects cross references. Please always make a small complete document that demonstrates the problem, so people can reproduce it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ... and your example most likely isn't minimal yet.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75841/cross-references-different-from-tableofcontents and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212952/redefine-ref-for-chapter-that-includes-the-part-number